# cling on Jupyter on Windows: Kernel cannot start

Tags: c++, jupyter, cling

**Background**: I am trying to install the cling c++ interpreter [here](https://github.com/root-project/cling). I am on a Windows and have had Anaconda running well, Jupyter notebook also working fine with the existing Python kernels. The installation process was smooth on the surface but there is Kernel error once I try to open Jupyter notebook on the installed Kernel.

(In the end I would hope to be able to use c++ with Jupyter notebook so if anyone has had any success please could you share your experience. On that, while the xeus-cling is not usable for Windows as many say, this cling appears to be a separate thing)

**The installation**: Here is what I have done:

1. Download the binary cling_2019-11-28_arm64.tar.bz2 **(is this correct for Windows?)** from
   https://root.cern.ch/download/cling/
2. Extract and place in Program Files folder
3. Following the instruction in [here](https://github.com/root-project/cling/blob/master/tools/Jupyter/README.md), add `C:\Program Files\cling_2019-11-28_arm64\bin` to the PATH variable
4. Activate base Anaconda environment
5. `cd  .../share/cling/Jupyter/kernel`
6. `pip install -e .`
7. `jupyter-kernelspec install --user cling-cpp11`

Every thing seems to be fine up to here, no warning/error.

**The error:** Then I load up my Jupyter notebook and try to run the cpp11 kernel, but it is unable to start with a long error traceback, the first/last items of which read:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1699, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 736, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 73, in post
    type=mtype))
 ... (omitted) ...
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 138, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

And on the cmd the following:

```
[E 14:39:14.265 NotebookApp] Failed to run command:
    ['jupyter-cling-kernel', '-f', 'path\\to\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-..(random string here)..json', '--std=c++11']
```

**The troubleshooting (1)**: ... appearing to suggest that it is unable to locate a `jupyter-cling-kernel`. But I do have file named `jupyter-cling-kernel` in the `.../Anaconda3/Scripts` folder, and this folder is also in my PATH variable. After opening it, I discovered it is a python file with only a few lines. Looks like it corresponds to the command above.

```
#!C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
# EASY-INSTALL-DEV-SCRIPT: 'clingkernel==0.0.2','jupyter-cling-kernel'
__requires__ = 'clingkernel==0.0.2'
__import__('pkg_resources').require('clingkernel==0.0.2')
__file__ = 'C:\\Program Files\\cling_2019-11-28_arm64\\share\\cling\\Jupyter\\kernel\\scripts\\jupyter-cling-kernel'
with open(__file__) as f:
    exec(compile(f.read(), __file__, 'exec'))
```

so then I modified my kernel.json file, adding the absolute python path (so that it knows to run it with python) and the absolute path of the jupyter-cling-kernel. (originally it was just `"argv:["jupyter-cling-kernel", "-f", ...`)

```
{
  "display_name": "C++11",
  "argv": [
      **"C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe",
      "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\jupyter-cling-kernel",**
      "-f",
      "{connection_file}",
      "--std=c++11"
  ],
  "language": "C++"

}
```

**The troubleshooting (2)**:... which indeed appears to be the right direction, at least it is running sth but now another error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-cling-kernel", line 7, in <modu
le>
    exec(compile(f.read(), __file__, 'exec'))
  File "C:\Program Files\cling_2019-11-28_arm64\share\cling\Jupyter\kernel\scrip
ts\jupyter-cling-kernel", line 3, in <module>
    from clingkernel import main
  File "c:\program files\cling_2019-11-28_arm64\share\cling\jupyter\kernel\cling
kernel.py", line 24, in <module>
    from fcntl import fcntl, F_GETFL, F_SETFL
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'
```

Now with some googling this fcntl appears to be sth not for Windows. So at this point I am wondering have I downloaded the wrong binary or should I modify this clingkernel.py file or do I need to do some compilation myself?

Again, if any of you knows of how to get the c++ run of Jupyter (on windows), appreciate if you could share your experience. Thanks.

Comment: If you do not run windows on arm64, you indeed have the wrong binary. You are likely looking for x86 or amd64

Comment: Thanks, maybe I haved mixed up arm64 and amd64 to think it is for Windows, so it looks like the only option is to build myself.

Comment: Just a heads up: The build takes several hours, about 30-40GB disk space and in an issue on github from mid 2017 somebody mentions that the jupyter kernel does not work on windows due to the python wrapper. If I were you, I would try the new linux subsystem or a VM :)

Comment: Lucky I see your note, I really just have 40 GB on my C. On linux VM, does that means all the libraries I need have to be re-compiled for Linux. (also means extra compile time and double disk space?)

Comment: Without knowing your specific situation, I can only say yes, unless there are binaries available.

Answer (score 2):

With Windows 10 + WSL, we can install xeus-cling for C++ on Windows

Steps includes

1. Enable Ubuntu on WSL
2. Install Miniconda
3. Setup Conda, Jupyter Notebook, Xeus-Cling

This cling notebook with the cpp environment can be made to run from a desktop shortcut. Steps are documented on [C/C++ Jupyter Notebook using xeus-cling - Windows WSL Setup](https://envyen.com/posts/2021-06-27-C-CPP-Jupyter-Notebook-Windows/)

Comment: yes that works!

Answer (score 0):

The cling interpreter has been packaged for conda-forge.

You can simply run

```
conda install cling -c conda-forge
```

and then run `cling`. However, unfortunately, the Jupyter kernel is not included with that build, and the windows build has some issues with IO operations which I am currently investigating.

Comment: Sorry I read your answer late. In fact I have run that command too and that has given me a cling program (which does work). Unfortunately as you pointed out that would not give me a Jupyter kernel. Thanks for the information still and I have in fact given up building it on Windows.

Comment: The xeus-cling jupyter kernel for cling can be installed with

conda install xeus-cling -c conda-forge.

Comment: Also, the only remaining issue with packaging cling and xeus-cling on windows is this one: https://github.com/root-project/cling/issues/300. If you have any idea on how to fix it, help would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try restarting the kernel by pressing o(not 0) twice.

Comment: can you mention how this helps / what it does in your answer?